Using Charles Proxy I'm trying to change the number of followers an Instagram account has but I can't figure out where is that information stored
I want to edit the follower count of an instagram account using Charles Proxy but I can't find where it stores it to access it. I've seen from other people that you need to edit the response body and you have things to use like breakpoint and map local.
I tried pretty much everything I could think of but not this program isn't used by that many people and information is hard to come by. I tried making live changes on the instagram account and I have seen that in the api folder that's where the information is stocked but it's not avaible to see unless you make some changes but I don't know how.
